# Bootstrap 4 Vertically Stacked Buttons, Each With Two Columns of Left Aligned Text

Tags: bootstrap-4, multiple-columns, vertical-alignment, buttongroup, leftalign

In Bootstrap 4, how can I create a list of vertically stacked buttons where each button contains two columns of left-aligned text?

Answer (score 0):

By using btn-block, I was able to expand the buttons to the width of their parent container:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
      <style>
        button span {
            float:left;
            width: 50%;
            text-align:left;
        }
        .btn-group-vertical {
            justify-content: flex-start;
        }
      </style>
    <h1 class="text-center">Two Left-Aligned Columns of Buttons in Bootstrap 4</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-3 btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="Vowels">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-outline-dark border-light">
                    <span>text</span>
                    <span>text</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-outline-dark border-light">
                    <span>more text</span>
                    <span>more text</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-3 btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="Vowels">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-outline-dark border-light">
                    <span>text</span>
                    <span>text</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-outline-dark border-light">
                    <span>text</span>
                    <span>more text</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-outline-dark border-light">
                    <span>text</span>
                    <span>even more text</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```